# python: looping through indeces in Excel and replacing with string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have an excel sheet with the following format:

[image]

Now what I'm looking to do is to loop trough each index cell in column A and assign all cells the same value until the next 0 is reached. so for example:

[image]

Now I have tried importing the excel file into a pandas dataframe and then using for loops to do this, but I can't seem to make it work. Any suggestions or directions to the appropriate method would be much appreciated! 
Thank you for your time

Edit:
Using @wen-ben's method: `s.index=pd.Series((s.index==0).cumsum()).map({1:'bananas',2:'cherries',3:'pineapples'})`

just enters the first element (bananas) for all cells in Column A

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have dataframe `s` using `cumsum`

```
s.index=pd.Series((s.index==0).cumsum()).map({1:'bananas',2:'cherries',3:'pineapples'})
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't seem to work for me. Just to clarify I am working of an excel file that I am then importing into a dataframe. The resulting excel file:    `bananas 0 INFORMATION INFORMATION INFORMATION
bananas 1 INFORMATION INFORMATION INFORMATION
bananas 2 INFORMATION INFORMATION INFORMATION
bananas 3 INFORMATION INFORMATION INFORMATION
bananas 4 INFORMATION INFORMATION INFORMATION
bananas 5 INFORMATION INFORMATION INFORMATION
bananas 6 INFORMATION INFORMATION INFORMATION
bananas 0 INFORMATION INFORMATION INFORMATION
bananas 1 INFORMATION INFORMATION INFORMATION`